# How to get response from loop running in another every interation?

Tags: java, ajax

I'm calling an inner class and running it as a future task:

```
Runnable r = new sendEmails(ids);
FutureTask task = new FutureTask(r, null);
ExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
scheduler.submit(task);
```

That looks like this:

```
private class sendLGORejectionEmails implements Runnable {

  private final String ids; 

  private sendLGORejectionEmails(String param) {
    ids = param;
  }

  public void run() {
    for (int i; i<=num_o_emails; i++) {
      Code that send emails and use 'ids' to do it;
    }
  }
}
```

After the task is submitted to the scheduler the code forwards the user to a webpage from that page I would like to use ajax to check up on the emails that are being sent (progress bar), I can use get to find out if the task is done or not but what i would like to do is to be able to ask for the value of i while the loop is processing. That way I could make a series of ajax posts and translate i into a progress point. How can I can I make a call that checks to see what the value of i is while the task is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your count variable in your for loop be defined outside of the loop.

In your code you can use a new counter `int globalCounter = 0;` outside of the loop.  Change the loop to use the global counter `for (; globalCounter <=num_o_emails; globalCounter ++)`.  This way you can call that `int` from outside the loop to see its current set value.

If you are accessing the number from outside this class though, and are intending to do changes to the number (add/subtract/etc.) make sure you are careful about race conditions to update the counter (for the loop and the outside method).

Comment: Thanks @Walls I figured this out only moments after I posted. Problem is now I can't get the ajax post to not fire off so fast.